# what is the best practice to setup Esxi server at home that can be accessed over the internet

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi

I have one static ip: 61.61.61.61 from my cable connection at home and a domain: www.mydomain.com that points to the IP.

I have a subversion sever on a linux vm1 - subversion.mydomain.com (192.168.1.100)
I have a Web server on a Windows vm2 - web.mydomain.com (192.168.1.101)
All the vms got their ip addresses from the router (DHCP).

I want to be able to (1). use the vSphere client to control host.
                     (2). remote desktop to access the Windows server.
                     (3). Web access both vm1 and wm2.

What's your suggestion regarding how to configure the network and secure the access. There is one Nic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, since you've already got the Windows server running (I'm assuming it is W2k3/8) then I would simply install RRAS on the Windows server and setup a VPN by allowing PPTP/GRE through the firewall by port forwarding/MIPing/whatever your router calls it.

Another solution would be to see if your router supports DD-WRT and setup a VPN using it.

Another would be to open up the ports necessary for RDP and the vsphere client using port forwarding as well, but this wouldn't be as secure as an actual VPN.

Another would be to install OpenVPN: http://openvpn.net/ as your VPN server and use that.

There are lots of choices, obviously...so you'll just have to find what works best for you.

Comment: Second the recommendation to keep the RDP and vSphere Management interfaces tucked up behind a VPN. They're not unsafe but you're better off keeping things like that behind some additional barrier.